# Using preg_match to match on email domain

Tags: php, regex

I'm attempting to execute a certain condition if, a submitted email address is of the gmail.com domain.

I have the following code, this reg ex is valid, and I'm passing a string to `preg_match` that contains the following 'test@gmail.co.uk', but the condition is never met. Can anyone suggest the issue here?

```
    if (preg_match('/\@gmail.co.uk/', $submitted_email))
        {
           //do stuff
        }
```

Comment: replace . with \. and also add `$` at the last

Comment: What's `var_dump($submitted_email)`?

Comment: @h2ooooooo test@gmail.co.uk in this case

Comment: @Liam I'd double-check that - your code works for me.

Comment: @Liam As choult mentioned [if the string is actually "test@gmail.co.uk", which I doubt, then it would work "fine" (although also match bleh@gmailxcoxukfoo because of your missing anchors and unescaped dots)](https://eval.in/536696). Please give an actual output of `var_dump($submitted_email)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex pattern to the following:

```
"/@gmail\.co\.uk$/i"
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of regex you can simply use PHP function [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) or [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) like as

```
if(strstr("client@example.com","@") == "@gmail.co.uk"){
   //
}
```

or

```
if(strpos("client@example.com","@gmail.co.uk")){
   //
}
```